# Force plugin dependency in gradle not working

Tags: dependencies, logback, cve, kotlin-gradle-plugin, ktlint

I'm using `org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint` plugin to kotlin formatting for my multi module project. The plugin uses `com.pinterest.ktlint 0.45.2` which has a dependency on `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.9`. This dependency has a CVE vulnerability so I'm trying to use the version which hasn't e.g. 1.4.14 but the gradle  `gradlew dependencyCheckAggregate` still complains and keep finding the version 1.2.12.

This is my how my root build.gradle looks like

```
plugins {
    id("org.owasp.dependencycheck") version "8.1.2"
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "11.0.0"
    ....
}


allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint")

    repositories {
        ...
        }
    }

    ktlint {
        // Force a new dependency to use new version of logback
        configurations.all {
            this.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
                if (this.requested.group == "ch.qos.logback") {
                    this.useVersion("1.4.14")
                }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

When I run gradlew dependencies I see the following out meaning it's indeed getting the new version:

```
+--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.9 -> 1.4.14
     |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.4.14
```

But when I execute dependencyCheckAggregate, I still get:

```
logback-classic-1.2.12.jar (pkg:maven/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic@1.2.12, cpe:2.3:a:qos:logback:1.2.12:*:*:*:*:*:*:*) : CVE-2023-6378
logback-core-1.2.12.jar (pkg:maven/ch.qos.logback/logback-core@1.2.12, cpe:2.3:a:qos:logback:1.2.12:*:*:*:*:*:*:*) : CVE-2023-6378
```

I'm not sure what should I do now. I already tried putting the resolution strategy at different places in the gradle. I even use force instead of eachDependency check and all results in the same output. Could someone help me out here?

EDIT: Strangely, it only works when I apply it to all the sub projects individually as well. It just doesn't work if I put it in just the root gradle.build.kts. So now the question is how to do it just once or I have to repeat it in all places?